# Weight painting and animation issue: armature moves vertices with zero weight

Tags: weight-painting

I'm just getting into rigging and animation with Blender and I've run into a quite odd-looking issue in a very basic step.

I'm doing a REALLY basic rig: I have a column (a tall cube with about 10 inner segments), which I rigged up with a bone chain, that is a straight line of 10 deforming bones. I used automatic weights and corrected it in weight paint where it was necessary (each bone should move 1 level of the 10 inner segments). However, what I get is that the bones not only move the vertices with weights over zero value (what I'm aiming is 4 vertices per bones), but each and every bone moves the bottom face of the mesh as well. The weight values of all 4 vertices of this bottom face is actually zero (or very close to it), in all vertex groups. At the same time 1-2 of its vertices act like they had about 0,75-0,9 weight values, when I rotate any bone, in Pose mode.

When googling it, I didn't even find similar issues, I'm quite paused what they problem may be. Has anyone met perhaps similar situation before? Thank you if you can help in any way

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi MoonBoots, thank you for reply! I've uploaded the file, I have put the link into the original post. Thank you again if you can look at it

Answer (score 1):

If you select one bottom vertex you can see that it is part of a lot of vertex groups:

[image]

You may say that the influence is pretty low so they should not move a lot, but it doesn't work that way. If a vertex is part of only one vertex group with a weight of 0.01, the bone (that has the same name as the vertex group) will move the vertex 100%. If a vertex is part of 2 groups with a weight of 0.01 for both the 2 vertex groups, the influence will be shared 50/50 by the 2 bones.

To fix your problem, select all these vertices and remove them from all groups, then assign to the vertex group they should be part of:

[image]

Comment: Hi MoonBoot, Thank you again for your reply. At first I tried to make the correction, you advised, only with the vertices in the bottom face, where the problem occured, but it didn't solve it. Doing it the correction with all vertices in the mesh (as you originally advised) did the magic and actually the mesh works now as planned.. Thank you very much for your help and your time! I see that you have given a lot of very precious support for a really long time now, to users like me, who are learning Blender.

Comment: Is there a way perhaps, we can appreciate your effort, beyond saying thank you? It would be really valid, as I did not really see other spot in the online space where self-learnens can get constant support when they get stuck.

Comment: it's ok, you're welcome  ;)   actually blenderartists is pretty active too https://blenderartists.org/c/support/9/l/latest

Comment: Just to get back to the original issue, for a short question: to me it's a bit mind-bending, that such a basic rigging of a very simple mesh needs such tedious correction you need to do by each vertex.. Is it really the general way how rigging should be done, even in case of complex rigging projects?

Comment: "it's ok, you're welcome ;) actually blenderartists is pretty active too" In that case, thank you a lot. You are doing very precious effort, I'm really stunned how you're doing it only as a give away for such a long period, in your free time. Thank you.

Comment: Actually parent With Automatic Weights should have worked better than that, I'm not sure what happened. Yes sometimes rigging is a bit tedious but I'm not sure there's any other way around. You don't have to do it vertex by vertex most of the time though  ;)

Comment: It is somewhat comforting, I can't really imagine how it would be done in character rigging with a 20k quad mesh..